# Database link name expected when executing update for oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm relatively new to coding and Java. I have an assignment where we build a GUI using JavaFX that interfaces with an oracle database with relevant data to be entered into our GUI product. In our GUI we are supposed to have an Update button which function is to update/alter a specific row in the database after making changes to the data in the GUI textfields/comboboxes. For my update action I have the button linked to I get the error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01729: database link name expected`. I have searched online for answers but I don't fully understand what this means and how to solve this issue. I set up my connection in the beginning of my code and included `static Connection con; Statement stmt;` earlier in my code. Any ideas/help would be appreciated

My code is below:

```
void updateEmp() {
        try {
            String updateQuery = "UPDATE employees SET firstname = '"
                    + tfFirstName.getText() + "', lastname = '"
                    + tfLastName.getText() + "', salary = "
                    + tfSalary.getText() + ", title = '"
                    + jobTitlesCbo.getValue() + "'";

            /*if (getDeptNum(deptTitlesCbo.getValue()) > 0
                    && getDeptNum(deptTitlesCbo.getValue()) < 6) {
                updateQuery = updateQuery + ", departmentid = '"
                        + getDeptNum(deptTitlesCbo.getValue()) + "'";
            }*/

            updateQuery = updateQuery + " WHERE employeeid = " + tfEmpID;
            stmt.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before going any further, follow a JDBC tutorial and **learn how to use `PreparedStatement`**. Do not use string concatenation to build SQL statements with user-supplied text values, since that will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities and SQL syntax errors.

Comment: Additionaly to the suggestion of **using bind varibles** check all values, that you try to add as parameters. Most probably some of those are not a String, but an object references such as `@021031023` which confuses Oracle to trigger the error `ORA-01729: database link name expected`